# The purpose of getting IC temperature or the die temperature?

Tags: integrated-circuit

In a brief time of working with Electronics IC , I have came across various IC's that provide the temperature sensor inside the die for the access of Engineer or embedded programmer.

The recent one I came across is MPU6050, I ran some Google search and came to an conclusion that it is being used for **Thermal Compensation** in order to improve accuracy over the varying temperature. 
What I want to know is, What exactly is the purpose of providing that information and what's the procedure to do it *When one doesn't have an Hi Tech laboratory to take the IC reading @ Various Temperature*?[MPU6050 Datasheet](https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf)

Comment: Just because you don't have a "hi tech laboratory" doesn't mean the other customers for that chip don't have one. The datasheet is for all the customers, not just you.

Comment: @ThePhoton Too late but what I actually was asking for how can it be utilized by me(One who doesn't have Hi End equipments). I am sure it could be of some use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some compensation just in static conditions. If the sensor is not rotating you should get 0 output (not counting the earth's rotation, which those cheap gyros are probably not sensitive enough to pick up).

Depending on how you point the accelerometers you can get the local gravity of around 1g on earth or close to zero.